# How to create data validation depending on sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template which contains some data validation columns.
Now, i have to do is, if the sheet is "Luxury" then the column F need to display data validation list "AC, NonAC" Options, other than that data validation list will be "Ordinary, Single".

How can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance for the help .

Comment: See this... http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/29/excel-data-validationcreate-dynamic-dependent-lists-vba/. Though it addresses a different issue but it shows you how to create dynamic DV List

Comment: Thank you so much Siddharth, can we do it with a formula ?

Comment: See this http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html and to get the sheetname you can use this formula `=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,256)`

Comment: i tried this formulae
=if((MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("]",CELL("filename"))+1,255))="luxury",indirect(luxry),indirect(nonlxry))
but it is getting error

Comment: i am able to get the sheetname from the above formulae but not able to populate the list

Comment: You already finished reading the Debra's article?

Comment: checked in this link contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html. But i am not able to get the right answer. could you please help in this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Siddharth Rout said above, I think the formula you're looking for is:

```
=IF(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,256)="Luxury"
    ,OR(F3="AC",F3="NonAC")
    ,OR(F3="Ordinary",F3="Single"))
```

Change Allow to Custom and put that in the Formula in the Data Validation window.  In this example, I'm adding the validation to F3.  That would have to change for each cell.  You can do it once and copy it down.

Comment: Thank you Rob, but this formula is not displaying the list in the cell to select the values